# Ubuntu 20.04, lsusb error. Undefined symbol libusb_get_port_number

Tags: usb, lsusb

I have recently been encountering an issue with lsusb and I suspect it is to do with libusb. Whenever I run it, I get the following error: `lsusb: symbol lookup error: lsusb: undefined symbol: libusb_get_port_number`.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling usbutils and the error remains.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

K